# Полнотекстовый поиск MySQL: возвращение найденных ключевых слов

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Допустим есть SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  articles
WHERE
  MATCH
    (title, body)
  AGAINST (
   '+Привет +"Как дела" +Отлично +"хорошее настроение" +"Салон Связи"'
   IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Как мне вернуть обратно + слова по которым нашлась статья?

P.S. интересует решение на PHP.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Приведите пример того, что нужно получить.

Comment: Запрос выше, в виде результата хочу что-то вроде "Статья найдена по запросу 'Привет, как дела, отлично' другие слова которые были использованы, в статье не найдены."

Comment: регекспом наверное. `if (preg_match('~AGAINST\h*\(\'\K[^\']+~i', $text, $match)) echo $match[0];`